# Unfinished verification, Missing method call for verify(mock) while writing a JUnit test case

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit, mockito

I am facing

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at systemservice.test1.SysParamsBuilderTest.testBuildProcessingInfoIf3(SysParamsBuilderTest.java:241)
```

I have checked for all the parameters and the object as well that is being passed to verify, But not able to figure out what is causing the above exception

The condition I am trying to test,

```
if( request.getProcessType() == IPRequest.IPREQUEST_TYPE_DE )
{

     LookInfoIf rdr = new MCLLookInfoReader();

    String origAnatomy = accessor.getValue(AttributeRepNames.ANATOMY_INFO.getTagName());
    String origView = accessor.getValue(AttributeRepNames.VIEW_INFO.getTagName());
    String origPatSize = accessor.getValue(AttributeRepNames.PATIENT_SIZE.getTagName());
    String mclPatSize = getMclPatientSize(origPatSize);
    String boneLook = rdr.getDefaultLook(origAnatomy,origView,core.MCLConstants.IMAGETYPEBONETAG,mclPatSize);
    String tissueLook = rdr.getDefaultLook(origAnatomy,origView,core.MCLConstants.IMAGETYPESOFTTISSUETAG,mclPatSize);

    params.setProcessingLookBone(boneLook);
    params.setProcessingLookTissue(tissueLook);
        params.setAnatomy(origAnatomy);
        params.setView(origView);
        params.setPatientSize(origPatSize);

}
```

Test case

```
@Test
    public void testBuildProcessingInfoIf3() throws Exception
    {
        IPRequest req=new IPRequest(1);//value of IPRequest.IPREQUEST_TYPE_DE

        IPSysParams iPSysParams = Mockito.mock(IPSysParams.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(IPSysParams.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(iPSysParams);

        TagAccessor accessor=Mockito.mock(TagAccessor.class);

        MCLLookInfoReader rdr=Mockito.mock(MCLLookInfoReader.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(MCLLookInfoReader.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(rdr);

        Mockito.when(accessor.getValue(AttributeRepNames.ANATOMY_INFO.getTagName())).thenReturn("ANATOMY_INFO");
        Mockito.when(accessor.getValue(AttributeRepNames.VIEW_INFO.getTagName())).thenReturn("VIEW_INFO");
        Mockito.when(accessor.getValue(AttributeRepNames.PATIENT_SIZE.getTagName())).thenReturn("PATIENT_SIZE");
        Mockito.when(rdr.getDefaultLook("ANATOMY_INFO","VIEW_INFO",core.MCLConstants.IMAGETYPEBONETAG,"All")).thenReturn("boneLook");
        Mockito.when(rdr.getDefaultLook("ANATOMY_INFO","VIEW_INFO",core.MCLConstants.IMAGETYPESOFTTISSUETAG,"All")).thenReturn("tissueLook");

        sysParamsBuilder.buildProcessingInfo(req, info);

        String origAnatomy=accessor.getValue(AttributeRepNames.ANATOMY_INFO.getTagName());
        assertEquals("ANATOMY_INFO",origAnatomy);

        String origView=accessor.getValue(AttributeRepNames.VIEW_INFO.getTagName());
        assertEquals("VIEW_INFO",origView);

        String origPatSize=accessor.getValue(AttributeRepNames.PATIENT_SIZE.getTagName());
        assertEquals("PATIENT_SIZE",origPatSize);

        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(sysParamsBuilder).invoke("getMclPatientSize",origPatSize);//line 241

        String boneLook=rdr.getDefaultLook("ANATOMY_INFO","VIEW_INFO",core.MCLConstants.IMAGETYPEBONETAG,"All");
        assertEquals("boneLook",boneLook);

        String tissueLook=rdr.getDefaultLook("ANATOMY_INFO","VIEW_INFO",core.MCLConstants.IMAGETYPESOFTTISSUETAG,"All");
        assertEquals("tissueLook",tissueLook);

        Mockito.verify(iPSysParams).setProcessingLookBone(boneLook);//line 244
        Mockito.verify(iPSysParams).setProcessingLookTissue(tissueLook);

        // fill the Anatomy View accrodingly
        Mockito.verify(iPSysParams,Mockito.times(1)).setAnatomy(origAnatomy);
        Mockito.verify(iPSysParams).setView(origView);
        Mockito.verify(iPSysParams).setPatientSize(origPatSize);

    }
```

stack trace

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at systemservice.test1.SysParamsBuilderTest.testBuildProcessingInfoIf3(SysParamsBuilderTest.java:241)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.

    at systemservice.test1.SysParamsBuilderTest.testBuildProcessingInfoIf3(SysParamsBuilderTest.java:244)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:104)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I have done other test cases in the same way and it has worked but I don't know why its not working here, also all the methods are public. please help me figure It out, Thanks in advance

Comment: Which lines are the lines 241 and 244 in your test method? The exception mentions those two specific lines

Comment: I have edited my post to show the line numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the exception message the problem is this line:

```
PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(sysParamsBuilder).invoke("getMclPatientSize",origPatSize);//line 241
```

Using google to search for `powermockito verifyprivate not working` I found the following page: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/CEdP24sb_HY

In short, if you want to use PowerMockito to spy on your objects you must not do

```
    SysParamsBuilder sysParamsBuilder = Mockito.spy(new SysParamsBuilder(...));
```

Instead you need to do

```
    SysParamsBuilder sysParamsBuilder = PowerMockito.spy(new SysParamsBuilder(...));
```

Otherwise if you try to verify private method invocations using PowerMockito you will get the exception you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the mockito error here; but my answer goes into a different direction: do **not** verify like this.

You are following an almost anti-pattern here: you want to use mocking/verify for almost each and any call that happens in your production code. This means that subtle changes in your production code will always directly impact your unit tests. Even when "contract" of your method stays the same, your unit tests break quickly when you are using this style of verification.

My suggestion: instead of **verifying** that an object sees a lot of setter calls, you could do *something* along the lines of:

```
Params expectedParams = ... 
Params actualParams = underTest.whatever();
assertThat(actualParams, is(expectedParams));
```

and if the simple "equals" check that the hamcrest `is` matcher is doing doesn't work here; you could still create your own matcher.

In other words: stay away from "micro managing" your production code in your unit tests.

Focus on writing code that allows to be tested **without** caring about **how** things are done internally. Instead, check the "output" that your methods produce!

Example: assume you do all that mocking verification on some params object as you do above; but then in the end, your method returns *some other* params object ... then your unit test might be passing; but the whole method is wrong, because it is giving you the wrong result.

Comment: If I don't mock the params then it will have null, and then wherever that param is used will also have null, I am writing test case for a production code that cannot be modified so I cannot change the implementation to make testing easier. I need to check each and everything that is happening inside the method so it will be easy for the developer to understand the purpose of that method. Here I am just trying to verify a couple of calls, but not able to figure out why its not happening, whereas in other places it is working.

Comment: OK, then my answer isn't of much help. But for the record: a test case that just "records" what the code does ... does **not at all** help a developer to better understand the production code. The only thing it achieves is that you can later "verify" that a refactored version of that source code is doing is making the same call. Don't trick yourself into believing that writing such tedious testcases has any deeper meaning or provides a lot of additional value to anybody.

Answer (score 0):

from your error message:

> error might show up because you verify either of: **final/private/equals()/hashCode()** methods.
>   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.

So check if any of this methods

```
    Mockito.verify(iPSysParams).setProcessingLookBone(boneLook);
    Mockito.verify(iPSysParams).setProcessingLookTissue(tissueLook);
    Mockito.verify(iPSysParams,Mockito.times(1)).setAnatomy(origAnatomy);
    Mockito.verify(iPSysParams).setView(origView);
    Mockito.verify(iPSysParams).setPatientSize(origPatSize);
```

is `final`.

Comment: None of these methods are final, all are public. I have mentioned it in my post